# How does a python web server recognize no file name in url?

Tags: python

I've written a very basic Python web server and am testing it using a web browser.

I can connect and load the page using:

`localhost:8080/index.htm`

I also have a default `404 Not Found` htm page that loads when some other words are entered instead of `index.htm`.

However, when no page is typed in, like this:
`localhost:8080` I would like for this to also load index.htm, but it does not recognize the fact that there is no file name.  Here is my code:

```
essage = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
print("The client request message is: %s" % message)
filename = message.split()[1]
print("filename is %s" % filename[0:])
try:
    if not filename:
        print("not filename")
        filename = "/index.htm"
    f = open(filename[1:])
    outputdata = f.read(1024)
    okmessage = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
except OSError:
    print ("There was an OSError")
```

And this is the output when I type in `localhost:8080` into the web browser:
(It should load the index.htm page)

```
Got a connection from ('192.168.1.9', 51453)
This request is served by thread 4568
The client request message is: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.9:8080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
filename is b'/'
There was an OSError
```

When typing `localhost:8080/index.htm` into the browser, the output is:

```
This request is served by thread 4568
The client request message is: b'GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.9:8080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
filename is b'/index.htm'
```

I changed the print statement on the filename to be `print("filename is %s" % filename[0:])` instead of `print("filename is %s" % filename[1:])` and now you can see that when no file name is typed into the browser, it prints out a file name that is `b'/'`  So this evaluates to true?

I'm running this on a Windows 7 machine.  Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE per @n9code

Comment: In Python 3, the return value of `socket.recv` is a bytes object, not a string.  `b'' == ''` yields `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
if filename == '':
        filename = "index.htm"
    f = open(filename[1:])
```

If you request with a file name, like `localhost:8080/filename.html`, you get `filename == '/filename.html'`, and then access your filename using `filename[1:]`. This all is fine, but when you detect that no filename is given in the request, you manually assign the `filename` variable the value `"index.html"` and then while doing `filename[1:]` you get `"ndex.html"`, which does not exist.

So a solution for your problem could be to change your code like this:

```
if not filename or filename == b'/':
        filename = "/index.htm"
    f = open(filename[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.  That doesn't seem to work.  It still thinks filename is `b''`and doesn't even enter the `if not filename` statement.  I checked this with a print statement inside the if statement.  Anything else you can think of?

Comment: when you get the filename value `b''`, it is an empty byte array, the boolean value of which is `False`. Thus, `not filename` in that case must be `True`, and the execution must enter the `if` block. Can you add more `print` to your code, and test with both filename present and without? Then post the `print` output in your question so we can analyse further.